# "Or" operator not working on window.location.pathname

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL:** Don't show `Navigation` component when the pathname includes either `/create-page` or `add-block`

Currently, the Navigation shows on both pages

```js
<Route
            path={[
              "/affiliate-code",
              "/dashboard",
              "/editor",
              "/locked",
              "/saved",
              "/notifications",
              "/:id",
              "/",
            ]}
            component={() =>
              window.location.pathname != ("/create-page" || "/add-block") && (
                <Navigation
                  key={window.location.pathname}
                  newNotification={newNotification}
                />
              )
            }
          />
```

Comment: didn't you mean window.location.pathname != "/create-page" || window.location.pathname != "/add-block"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an `OR` operator like so, you need to compare each value in the eval statement. If you want 1 statement I would suggest something like this:

```
!["/create-page","/add-block"].includes(window.location.pathname) && (
...
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: Also, this doesn't work with ``` "/:id",```. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: what defines `id` ? based on that we can make some sort of check.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by define in this case. When someone goes to an :id url (e.g., /roger or /michael, I don't want the navigation component to show

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.location.pathname != ("/create-page" || "/add-block")`

to

`window.location.pathname != "/create-page" && window.location.pathname != "/add-block"`

The first one will always end up to be `window.location.path != "/create-page"` because string is a truthy value. But still the case of `/create-page` should have passed. Maybe the string isn't exact so you can use `.includes` for the purpose.